# Cannot redeclare MyClass - but it's only declared once

Tags: 8, media

I'm trying to port an image effect from D7 to D8.

I've got Drupal to list the plugin, but when I try to use it I get a WSOD with "Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Drupal\image\Plugin\ImageEffect\EffectMagic".

I've checked and there is no other declaration of this class anywhere.

My file is in `mymod/src/Plugin/ImageEffect/EffectMagic.php`
and it looks like this (nb. content of functions is removed)

```
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\image\Plugin\ImageEffect\EffectMagic.
 */

namespace Drupal\image\Plugin\ImageEffect;

use Drupal\Core\Image\ImageInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\image\ConfigurableImageEffectBase;

/**
 * Scales and crops an image resource.
 *
 * @ImageEffect(
 *   id = "image_effect_magic",
 *   label = @Translation("Effect Magic"),
 *   description = @Translation("Use ImageMagic command line to process images.")
 * )
 */
class EffectMagic extends ConfigurableImageEffectBase {
  public function buildConfigurationForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  public function validateConfigurationForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  public function submitConfigurationForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  public function applyEffect(ImageInterface $image)
  public function transformDimensions(array &$dimensions, $uri)
  public function getSummary()
  public function defaultConfiguration()
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if is the cause of the problem, but I am pretty sure your module should define it's own namespace, not use the same namespace as the image module: `namespace Drupal\mymod\Plugin\ImageEffect;`

Comment: Took me some long days to figure things out as well ;)

Comment: @Neograph734 That would make a good answer if you have time to put it in :)

Comment: Give me a second to write a detailed answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are creating a custom module, you have to make sure your module registers its own namespace. In the current situation your module is attempting to use the namespace of the image module `namespace Drupal\image\Plugin\ImageEffect;`. Where you should actually be using a namespace of your own module `namespace Drupal\mymod\Plugin\ImageEffect;`

Then if you require functions of the image module, you can (as you have done already) load the other classes and functions with `use`. Like `use Drupal\image\ConfigurableImageEffectBase;`.